# Sorting out headphones and speakers sound

Tags: windows-vista, skype, windows-media-player

Basically I want everything but windows media player to go through the headphones, I can get skype to go through the headphones, and the music to go through the speakers, but I also need video game sound to go through the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Access the `Sound` option via `Control Panel`:

1. Make sure both playback devices are enabled
2. Choose your headphones as the default device by right clicking on them and selecting `Set as Default Device`
3. Open Windows Media Player
4. Click `Organize` → `Options`
5. Click the `Devices` tab
6. Select `Speakers` and click `Properties`
7. Select your speakers from the `Select the audio device` drop-down box. (instead of `Default Audio Device`).

Then you should be all sorted, all volume will play through your default audio device, in this instance your headphones. Only Windows Media Player will output audio through your speakers.

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot of the Speaker selection screen

[image]

In my instance, I have the option between the Default Audio Device & Speakers (Siberia V2 Illuminated).

So choose the non default audio device / speaker option you see there as the default audio channel.

Comment: I get lost at step 7. I think I'm doing something wrong, sorry i'm not good at this...

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the screen & what you should select.